# Unable to install any ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am trying to install Rails on my Mac. I keep getting a Jruby error or something of the sort:

```
gem install rails
Loading jruby-openssl in a non-JRuby interpreter
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- jruby (LoadError)
Loading jruby-openssl in a non-JRuby interpreter
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- jruby (LoadError)
Loading jruby-openssl in a non-JRuby interpreter
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- jruby
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

It looks like I have JRuby installed, which I think happened after I installed Java to install Netbeans. I used RVM to update ruby to 2.4. How do I get back to installing gems?

Thanks

Comment: You can always `rvm implode` and start over if you need to by reinstalling RVM.

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```